# An error related to mongoDB & mongoose , express.js "MongooseError: Operation ausers.insertOne() buffering timeout"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, runtime-error, mongodb-atlas

`MongooseError: Operation ausers.insertOne() buffering timeout after 1000ms`
I am trying to send post request through Thunder-client in vs code to my mongoDB atlas, but it's getting failed, but my data from database is getting fetched successfully.
The output is expected to be "Success:true" when we send post request

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  //THis  is used to make schema/pattern
```

const mongoDB = async () => {
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;  //This
const url = "mongodb+srv://abhiarjun:Password@foodzcluster.uqbljhv.mongodb.net/MyFood'z?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const databasename = "MyFood'z"; // Database name

await  MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}).then((client) => {

```
    const connect = client.db(databasename);
    console.log("connected successfully ✅✅....!");
    console.log("Below is your mongoDB data ");

    // Connect to collection
    const collection = connect.collection("food_item");

    collection.find({}).toArray().then((ans) => 
    {
      // console.log(ans);
        console.log("Finished......!");
    });
    
}).catch((err) => {

    // Printing the error message
    console.log(err.Message,"Something went wrong ⚠️⚠️⚠️ ")
})
```

}
module.exports = mongoDB;

```
const mongoosee = require("mongoose").mongoose;
```

const {Schema } = mongoosee ;

const UserSch = new Schema({
name:{
type:String, required:true
},
location:{
type:String, required:true
},
email:{
type:String, required:true
},
password:{
type:String, required:true
},
Date:{
type:Date, default:Date.now
},
});

module.exports = mongoosee.model('ausers', UserSch)

1. List item

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z04U.jpg) [Router Comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PC1k.jpg)[Model comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHvXC.jpg)[Index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DphO2.jpg)[Thunder client req page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkenx.jpg)[DB connection comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRpcd.jpg)

Comment: We are having mongo issues today, our code cannot connect to our database, and my databases wont show up in atlas. Its possible its not your code, and is an issue their side. Although there service status page shows no issues reported, but I have been chatting to them all day as they try to resolve the issues with my db.